# iPhone OpenGL ES app killed on iPad when using "2x" button

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, opengl-es, memory-management

Hey, I got kind of a weird issue here.

I have an iPhone-only OpenGL ES app which runs fine on all iPhone and iPod touch models supported.

When running on the iPad, it runs on an iPhone-sized window as expected, and pressing the "2x" button once scales up the window to twice the size, as expected, and the app continues to run without problems.

But if the user taps the "2x" button 3 or 4 times quickly, the app is killed with the `Program received signal:  "0"` message (which, from what I understand, means the OS killed my app for using too much memory, is that right?)

What I really do not understand is what in my app could possibly be using up more memory when the iPad scales the window up and down? As far as I know there's not even any way for my app to tell if and when the iPad is doing that. I don't know if the fact I'm using OpenGL ES is related or not, but that issue doesn't happen on any of the Cocoa Touch apps I have - though it also doesn't happen on the other two OpenGL ES apps I have. And this app does use more memory than any of the other ones.

Anyone ever had or even heard of this problem? Googling gave me nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just adding this so there's some kind of an answer here...

I never figured out what the hell was going on with the 2x button.

The way I fixed it back then was to optimize memory usage as much as I could, lazy-load all that I could and unload again when not in use.
Weird that it never complains about memory when running on any of the supported iPhone or iPod touch models, even the older ones, but it got killed on the iPad ONLY when pressing the 2x button repeatedly and quickly... I guess that's always gonna be a mystery to me.

Answer (score 1):

Since no one has posted with a direct answer (your situation might be a little vague), I have a suggestion for how to move forward and gather more information on what might be causing your problem.

Check out the Instruments in Xcode which can identify memory leaks:
[Instruments User Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Or for an even friendlier introduction, here's a video that address performance issues, including memory leaks (and how to find them).  [iOS Performance Optimization Video](http://developer.apple.com/videos/iphone/#video-essentials-maxperformance)

Comment: Hey Gregg, thanks for your answer. I've already checked the memory usage using Leaks, Allocations and Memory Monitor instruments on the Instruments utility. No memory leaks were detected in any situation. The app will run fine and get no memory warnings on any device unless the user scales the window up and down quickly on the iPad. I have no idea how that scaling animation could affect my app.

Comment: Best of luck then, I'm just learning the iOS platform so that exhausts all the help I can offer! :)

One of the test apps I made starting crashing on load and nothing I could see was causing it.  I made a new project and copied the code that was crashing into it - and the problem was gone.  Maybe try that?

Comment: @filipe - What does Memory Monitor report before and after you hit the 2X enlarging button?  Does the absolute memory size of your application grow?  Also, if you take a heap shot in ObjectAlloc before and after hitting the magnification button, then another heap shot after hitting the button again, are there any memory elements that show up as being added after that button is pressed each time?